# Set page of viewpager in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have a component that is navigated to from the drawer menu,the name of the component is `Servicecategory`, now I want to navigate to a another component from this `Servicecategory`, The name of this component is `Home`, this Home component conatains a view pager, I want to navigate to home component and change the view pager to a specific page on navigate from `ServiceCategory` i.e `this.setpage(0)`, is this possible, this is my code below

**SERVICECATEGORY**

```
 import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { trueBrowse,trueCart, trueHome, trueMessages, trueServices,falseBrowse,
falseCart, falseHome,falseMessages, falseServices} from "../actions/index";

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return { home: state.home, browse: state.browse,cart: state.cart, messages:  state.messages };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    trueBrowse: browse => dispatch(trueBrowse(browse)),
    trueServices: services => dispatch(trueServices(services)),
    trueHome: home => dispatch(trueHome(home)),
    trueMessages: messages => dispatch(trueMessages(messages)),
    trueCart: cart => dispatch(trueCart(cart)),
    falseServices: services => dispatch(falseServices(services)),
    falseMessages: messages => dispatch(falseMessages(messages)),
    falseHome: home => dispatch(falseHome(home)),
    falseCart: cart => dispatch(falseCart(cart)),
    falseBrowse: browse => dispatch(falseBrowse(browse))
    };

    };
class reduxServicesCategory extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
    drawerLockMode: 'locked-closed'

};
stateChanger() {
    this.props.trueHome("home");
    this.props.falseMessages("messages");
    this.props.falseBrowse("soo");
    this.props.falseCart("cart");
    this.props.trueServices("services");
    //ON navigate to Land, I want to change the view of the view pager, that is currently in land
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Land');
}
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        search: false
    };
}
showSearch(){

    this.setState({search: true},);
};
render(){
    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',height: 80,backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
                marginBottom: 15,
                justifyContent: 'center',width: '100%',alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack(null)}>
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons style={{position: 'absolute',left: 10,top: StatusBar.currentHeight
                    }} name="arrow-left" size={30} color="#535461"/>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                {this.state.search?
                    <TextInput
                        autoFocus={true}
                        ref="search"
                        placeholder="Search..."
                        returnKeyType={'search'}
                        placeholderStyle={{fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'mont-semi',}}
                        placeholderTextColor="#000"
                        underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}
                        style={{
                            position: 'absolute',top: StatusBar.currentHeight-5,
                            backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',width: '65%',alignSelf: 'center',
                            fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'mont-medium', color: '#000',
                        }}/>:<Text style={{fontFamily: 'mont-semi',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: '#000',}}>
                        Service Category
                    </Text>}
                {this.state.search?
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() => this.setState({search: false})}>
                        <MaterialIcons style={{position: 'absolute',right: 10,
                            top: StatusBar.currentHeight
                        }}  name="cancel" size={30} color="#535461"/>
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>:
                    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.showSearch.bind(this)}>
                        <MaterialIcons style={{position: 'absolute',right: 10,
                            top: StatusBar.currentHeight
                        }}  name="search" size={30} color="#535461"/>
                    </TouchableNativeFeedback>}
            </View>
            <ScrollView>
            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',marginBottom: 25,
                justifyContent: 'space-evenly'}}>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback
                onPress={this.stateChanger.bind(this)}>
                <View style={styles.cats}>
                 <View style={styles.icon}>
                     <Image  resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                             source={require('../makeup_icon.png')}/>
                 </View>
                 <Text style={styles.iconDes}>
                     {'\n'}MAKEUP ARTIST
                 </Text>
             </View>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback
                    onPress={this.stateChanger.bind(this)}>
                <View style={styles.cats}>
                    <View style={styles.icon}>
                        <Image  resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                                source={require('../makeup_icon.png')}/>
                    </View>
                    <Text style={styles.iconDes}>
                        {'\n'}MAKEUP ARTIST
                    </Text>
                </View>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
            </View>
```

**LANDCOMPONENT(HOME)**

```
   <ViewPagerAndroid style={{flex: 1}} initialPage={0}
                              onPageSelected={this.onPageSelected.bind(this)}
                              ref={(viewPager) => {
                                  this.viewPager = viewPager
                              }}>
                <View style={{flex: 1}} key="1">

                    {this.props.services ?
                        <View style={{
                            width: '100%',
                            marginTop: 10,
                        }}>
                            <Services navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                        </View>
          <View style={{flex: 1}} key="2">
                    <Messages/>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex: 1}} key="3">
                    <Browse navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                </View>
```

**APP.JS(Drawer)**

```
  const screens = createStackNavigator({
Home: {
    screen: ServiceDetail,
},
Signup: {
    screen: Signup
},
Login: {
    screen: Login
},
Land: {
    screen: Home,
},
Find: {
    screen: Find
},
Shop: {
    screen: Shop
},
SetCat: {
    screen: ServicesCategory
},
ServiceProfile: {
    screen: ServiceProfile
},
ServiceDetail: {
    screen: On,
},
JobBid: {
    screen: JobBid
}


});

const RootStack = DrawerNavigator(
{
    drawer: {
        screen: screens
    }
},
{
    drawerWidth: Width * (80 / 100),
    contentComponent: (props) => (

        <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc'}}>
            <LinearGradient colors={['#EE8F62', '#f2ac88']}
                            style={{width: '100%', height: 190}}>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center',
                    paddingTop: 20, justifyContent: 'center', alignContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        width: 150, height: 150,
                        borderRadius: 150 / 2,
                    }}>
                        <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                               source={require('./profile.png')}/>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginBottom: 13}}>
                        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'mont-semi', color: '#fff', fontSize: 20}}>
                            Jane Doe</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'mont', color: '#fcfcfc', fontSize: 18, marginTop: 10}}>
                            Profile</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </LinearGradient>
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc'}}>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>
                    props.navigation.navigate('Shop', {})}>
                    <View style={{
                        height: 60,
                        width: '100%',
                        backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        paddingLeft: 20,
                        paddingRight: 10,
                        paddingTop: 10,
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        alignContent: 'center',
                        justifyContent: 'center'
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            flexDirection: 'row', height: 40,
                            width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#f2f2f2', borderRadius: 3,
                            alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 10
                        }}>
                            <View style={{height: 21, width: 23}}><Image
                                resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                                source={require('./cart.jpg')}/></View>
                            <Text style={{
                                marginLeft: 23, fontFamily: 'mont-medium', fontSize: 14
                                , color: '#F3B690'
                            }}>Shop by Category</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>
                    props.navigation.navigate('SetCat', {})}>
                    <View style={{
                        height: 60, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
                        flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 10
                    }}>
                        <View style={{height: 23, width: 23}}><Image
                            resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                            source={require('./recruitment.jpg')}/></View>
                        <Text style={{
                            marginLeft: 23, fontFamily: 'mont-medium', fontSize: 14
                            , color: '#615D5D'
                        }}>Sẹlẹ Services</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableNativeFeedback>
                <View style={{
                    height: 60, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
                    flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 10
                }}>
                    <View style={{height: 23, width: 23}}><Image
                        resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                        source={require('./payment-method.png')}/></View>
                    <Text style={{
                        marginLeft: 23, fontFamily: 'mont-medium', fontSize: 14
                        , color: '#615D5D'
                    }}>Sell on Sẹlẹ</Text>
                </View>
                <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={() =>
                    props.navigation.navigate('Login', {})}>
                    <View style={{
                        height: 60, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#fcfcfc',
                        flexDirection: 'row', paddingLeft: 20, paddingTop: 10
                    }}>
                        <View style={{height: 21, width: 23}}>
                            <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{alignSelf: 'center', flex: 1}}
                                   source={require('./account.jpg')}/></View>
                        <Text style={{
                            marginLeft: 23, fontFamily: 'mont-medium', fontSize: 14
                            , color: '#615D5D'
                        }}>My Account</Text>
                    </View></TouchableNativeFeedback>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
},

{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
}
, {}
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `componentDidUpdate`

Like this

```
componentDidUpdate(){
    if(this.props.home && this.props.services){
        this.viewPager.setPage(0);
    }
}
```